# How can I refresh my partial view on my parent index after a modal update to add new information?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am certain this question has been asked before, I don't think there is anything unique about my situation but let me explain. I have my Index View (Parent), on that Index View there is a partial View Dataset Contacts "links" (child), I have an Add Contact button, which pops a Modal and allows me to submit the form data to add to the database, when I return I want to only refresh the partial view of links. Note: the Controller Action Dataset_Contacts below needs to fire in order to refresh the partial view (child). It might go without saying, but I don't see this happening with my current code. Any assistance will be appreciated.

on my Index View index.cshtml I have the following code to render my partial View

```
 <div class="section_container2">
                        @{ Html.RenderAction("Dataset_Contacts", "Home"); }
                    </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Dataset_Contacts()
        {
            // Retrieve contacts in the Dataset (Contact)
            //Hosted web API REST Service base url  
            string Baseurl = "http://localhost:4251/";
           
            var returned = new Dataset_Contact_View();
            var dataset = new Dataset();
            var contacts = new List<Contact>();
            var contact_types = new List<Contact_Type>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
               
                dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dataset>(datasetResponse);
 
                contact_types = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact_Type>>(ContactTypeResponse);

                // Set up the UI
                var ds_contact = new List<ContactView>();
                foreach (Contact c in dataset.Contact)
                {
                    foreach (Contact_Type t in contact_types)
                    {
                        if (c.Contact_Type_ID == t.Contact_Type_ID)
                        {
                            var cv = new ContactView();
                            cv.contact_id = c.Contact_ID;
                            cv.contact_type = t.Description;
                            returned.Dataset_Contacts.Add(cv);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
                     
                    return PartialView(returned);
        }
```

Here is my Partial View Dataset_Contacts.cshtml

```
 @model ResearchDataInventoryWeb.Models.Dataset_Contact_View
<table>
    @{
        var count = 1;

        foreach (var ct in Model.Dataset_Contacts)
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                @Html.Raw("<tr>")
                @Html.Raw("<td>")
                <a href="#" onclick="ViewContact(@ct.contact_id);"><span class="link" style="margin-left:10px;">@ct.contact_type</span></a>
                @Html.Raw("</td>")
                count++;
            }

            else if (count == 2)
            {
                @Html.Raw("<td>")

                <a href="#" onclick="ViewContact(@ct.contact_id);"><span class="link" style="margin-left:300px;">@ct.contact_type</span></a>
                @Html.Raw("</td>")

                @Html.Raw("</tr>")
                count = 1;

            }
        }

    }

</table>
```

Also on my Index.cshtml is my Add Contact button, which pops a modal

```
  <div style="float:right;">
                            <a href="#" onclick="AddContact();"><span class="link" style="padding-right:5px;">Add</span></a>
                        </div>
```

jquery for the Modal:

```
var AddContact = function () {

        var url = "../Home/AddContact"
        $("#myModalBody").load(url, function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        })


    };
```

Controller action for AddContact

```
 public ActionResult AddContact()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Modal for AddContact.cshtml

```
@model ResearchDataInventoryWeb.Models.Contact
<form id="contactForm1">
    <div class="section_header2">Contact</div>
    <div style="padding-top:5px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">UCID/Booth ID</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Booth_UCID, new { placeholder = "<Booth/UCID>", @class = "input-box" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Type</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="input-box" id="contact_type">
                        <option value="contact_type">Contact Type*</option>
                        <option value="dataset_admin">Dataset Admin</option>
                        <option value="dataset_Provider">Dataset Provider</option>
                        <option value="department">Department</option>
                        <option value="external_collaborator">External Collaborator</option>
                        <option value="principal_investigator">Principal Investigator</option>
                        <option value="research_center">Research Center</option>
                        <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Name</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_Name, new { placeholder = "<First Name>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { placeholder = "<Last Name>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Email</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder = "<Email 1>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email_2, new { placeholder = "<Email 2>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Phone</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone_Number, new { placeholder = "<Phone 1>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone_Number_2, new { placeholder = "<Phone 2>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Job Title</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title_Role, new { placeholder = "<Job Title>", @class = "input-box" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Organization</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input-box" type="text" placeholder="<Organization>" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <div style="padding-left:10px; margin-top:10px;">
            <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centerButton" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <div style="margin-left:30px">
            <submit id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:14px"><span class="smallText_red" style="padding:30px">SAVE</span></submit>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:30px">
            <submit class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:14px"><span class="smallText_red" style="padding:30px">REMOVE</span></submit>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var frm = $('#contactForm1').serialize()
             
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddContact/",
                data: frm,
                success: function () {
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                }
            })

        })
    })

</script>
```

and lastly Action for [HttpPost] AddContact(Contact data)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddContact(Contact data)
    {

        // Update the Database here
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution:**

**1. Change ActionResult to JsonResult**

```
    {
        // Update the Database code
        // END

        return Json(new
        {
           dbUpdateResult = "success"                
        });
        
    }
```

**2. In Ajax:**

```
//Ajax code
...

success: function (ajaxRespond) {
   if(ajaxRespond.dbUpdateResult == "success"){
     $("#myModal").modal("hide");
     reloadTable()
   }             
}
```

**Then you can use 1:**

```
function reloadTable(){
  $('#CONTAINER_ID').load('@Url.Action("Dataset_Contacts", "Home")');
}
```

**Or 2:**

```
function reloadTable(){
  let myurl = '@Url.Action("Dataset_Contacts", "Home")';
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myurl,           
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                            
        $("#CONTAINER_ID").html(data);
    },
    error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {  
        console.log(requestObject, error, errorThrown);
        alert("Error: can not update table")
    }
  });
}
```

So you reload your partial view after successful dbupdate. Please tell me, if I'm wrong...

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: This worked for me, I have to do the update to the database to be certain, but my main issue was that I didn't see the controller firing after the update, where the refresh from the database happens, now at least in debug more it is hitting the controller on initial load, and on the return, and it is NOT hitting the controller for the parent page except in the initial load. Thanks again!!